# How do I split a vector to subvectors with a specified subvector lengths in R

Tags: r, split

I want R to split a vector to subvectors with the lengths of each subvectors being specified.

If I have a vector `ts` which ranges from 1 to 30, I like to split it to subvectors with the length of the subvectors to be `4 4 4 4 2 2 2 2 4 2`

```
ts<-1:30
t<-c(4 4 4 4 2 2 2 2 4 2)
split(ts, each=t) # divides the series into blocks
```

** Result that I want**

```
# 1 2 3 4
#5 6 7 8
#9 10 11 12
#13 14 15 16
#17 18
#19 20
#20 22
#23 24
#25 26 27 28
#29 30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create a grouping index with `rep` using the 't' vector and `split` the 'ts' vector

```
split(ts, rep(seq_along(t), t))
#$`1`
#[1] 1 2 3 4

#$`2`
#[1] 5 6 7 8

#$`3`
#[1]  9 10 11 12

#$`4`
#[1] 13 14 15 16

#$`5`
#[1] 17 18

#$`6`
#[1] 19 20

#$`7`
#[1] 21 22

#$`8`
#[1] 23 24

#$`9`
#[1] 25 26 27 28

#$`10`
#[1] 29 30
```

#### data

```
ts <- 1:30
t <- c(4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2)
```

NOTE: Both `ts` and `t` are function names.  it is better to specify object names with a different name

Comment: I can not reproduce your result

Comment: @DanielJames  I showed a reproducible example with the `data`.  The result is using  `R 3.6.0`

Comment: @DanielJames  What is the result you are getting?

Comment: `mapply(function(x, y) a[x:y], c(1, head(cumsum(b) + 1, -1)), cumsum(b))` also works but is not as simple.

Comment: @d.b write it out as an answer and state your data